# keyframes dosent work in firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

i used keyframes in order that to make a plus effect on a text which every 15s make a plus effect this work in chrome but doesnt work in Firefox. 
i didnt know how can i make a 15s delay between each pulse effect so i try to use more percent in work i dont khow is it tru or not

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse_animation {
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
3% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
4% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
6% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.08); }
8% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
10% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
12% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
14% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
16% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
18% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
20% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
22% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
24% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
26% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
28% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
30% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
32% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
34% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
36% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
38% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
42% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
44% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
46% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
48% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
52% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
54% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
56% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
58% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
60% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
62% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
64% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
66% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
68% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
70% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
72% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
74% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
76% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
78% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
80% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
82% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
84% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
86% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
88% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
90% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
92% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
94% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
96% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
98% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
```

}

```
@-moz-keyframes pulse_animation {
0% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
3% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
4% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
6% { -moz-transform: scale(1.08); }
8% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
10% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
12% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
14% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
16% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
18% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
20% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
22% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
24% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
26% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
28% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
30% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
32% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
34% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
36% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
38% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
40% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
42% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
44% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
46% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
48% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
50% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
52% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
54% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
56% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
58% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
60% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
62% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
64% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
66% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
68% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
70% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
72% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
74% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
76% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
78% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
80% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
82% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
84% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
86% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
88% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
90% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
92% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
94% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
96% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
98% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
```

}

```
@keyframes pulse_animation {
0% { transform: scale(1); }
3% { transform: scale(1); }
4% { transform: scale(1); }
6% { transform: scale(1.08); }
8% { transform: scale(1); }
10% { transform: scale(1); }
12% { transform: scale(1); }
14% { transform: scale(1); }
16% { transform: scale(1); }
18% { transform: scale(1); }
20% { transform: scale(1); }
22% { transform: scale(1); }
24% { transform: scale(1); }
26% { transform: scale(1); }
28% { transform: scale(1); }
30% { transform: scale(1); }
32% { transform: scale(1); }
34% { transform: scale(1); }
36% { transform: scale(1); }
38% { transform: scale(1); }
40% { transform: scale(1); }
42% { transform: scale(1); }
44% { transform: scale(1); }
46% { transform: scale(1); }
48% { transform: scale(1); }
50% { transform: scale(1); }
52% { transform: scale(1); }
54% { transform: scale(1); }
56% { transform: scale(1); }
58% { transform: scale(1); }
60% { transform: scale(1); }
62% { transform: scale(1); }
64% { transform: scale(1); }
66% { transform: scale(1); }
68% { transform: scale(1); }
70% { transform: scale(1); }
72% { transform: scale(1); }
74% { transform: scale(1); }
76% { transform: scale(1); }
78% { transform: scale(1); }
80% { transform: scale(1); }
82% { transform: scale(1); }
84% { transform: scale(1); }
86% { transform: scale(1); }
88% { transform: scale(1); }
90% { transform: scale(1); }
92% { transform: scale(1); }
94% { transform: scale(1); }
96% { transform: scale(1); }
98% { transform: scale(1); }
100% { transform: scale(1); }
```

}

```
.first-visit{
-webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
-webkit-animation-duration: 18000ms;
-webkit-transform-origin:40% 40%;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;


-moz-animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
-moz-animation-duration: 18000ms;
-moz-transform-origin:40% 40%;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-delay: 2s;



animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
animation-duration: 18000ms;
transform-origin:40% 40%;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

}

Comment: Seems like a bug in firefox 18. I had my animations working before, and when i updated ff to 18 my animation stopped working. I had similar code like yours.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
-moz-animation-name: pulse_animation;
```

instead of

```
-moz-animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
```

the animation name is an identifier, not a string, and hence shouldn't be in quotes.